# Update item custom quantity and salable quantity value after place order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, plugin, stock

I need to **decrease** purchased item **saleable** quantity with custom value (x* ordered_qty) after place order in Magento 2.Right now I'm using the following observer and class to update the quantity of purchased items.

**Event Xml**

```
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
       <observer name="Update_customstock" instance="Company\MyMoudle\Observer\UpdateStock" />
   </event>
```

Observer Class

```
class UpdateStock implements ObserverInterface
{


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

     $orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $orderItems = $orderData->getAllVisibleItems();
               foreach($orderItems as $item) {
                      if($flag_variable) {
                $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
                $stockItem->setQty($new_qty);
               $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($item->getSku(), $stockItem);
                     }
        }
    }

}
```

**Issue**

But it's deceasing salable quantity double of my sent value and quantity also updating as sent value.

**What I need**

I need if the order is placed then only the decrease the salable quantity and once the shipment is created then decrease the quantity.

**Please suggest any solution with a plugin or observer.**

Comment: Your code is not working for me. Order is not placing.

Comment: Please check your logs file and share the error message with me,

Answer (score 1):

Use the following event global scope. Ex. VendorName/ModuleName/etc/events.xml

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

For Paypal payment method, use the following:

```
paypal_express_place_order_success
```

Comment: my mentioned event is working but as the explained issue is in salable qunitiy and product quntity value issue

Comment: Don't use sales_order_place_after event, this event will call every time when order will save. Ex. $order->save(). If you want something after the order place then use the above event that I answer.

Comment: Using your event getting the same issue.example SKU with qty 100 and 100 salable qty.i ordered 1 qty and stock effected as qty 99 and 98 saleable qty. I think my code is updating qty instead of salable qty.any idea?

Comment: you got any solution?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you got any solution? Please share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Catalog -> inventory on the store configuration in the back end.

In the stock options, select No to Decrease Stock When Order is Placed. Then you will get what you needed.

Comment: I used a module from https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2-admin-low-stock-notification to send a notification mail to the admin when any product stock quantity below 20,10,5. Also, I need additional customization to send a notification mail for out of stock product to the admin. If you have any idea can you please share your thoughts